# How to use VPN connection from VM on host?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vpn, vmware-fusion

The situation is fallowing:
I have VM on VMware that I'm using to connect to remote server.
But it's a bit tedious to use always VM.

So my question is there is a way to connect on VM, minimize it and somehow use connection on host?

P.S I can connect to VM via ssh from host via bridget connection, but its not enough.

P.S2 Im using VMware Fusion on MacOsX Mojave, butif its possible to make it work with Virtual Box, is fine with me.

More info on system:
Host: MacOsX Mojave
Guest: Lubuntu 18.04
VM: VMware Fusion/Virtualbox

Comment: What OS and what VPN software is the VM running?

Comment: Its Mojave, and VMware Fusion

Comment: and which OS is the guest inside the VM? One way might be to have the guest run a socks5 proxy, but we can't easily give you any more info without knowing what OS the guest is running.

Comment: Its Lubuntu 18.04